# In-place editor buttons in footer missing

Tags: panels, theming

I installed the Panels in-place editor which, in principle, should allow me to edit page layouts on the front-end.

But the two big buttons "Customize this Page” and “Change Layout” which should show up at the bottom of the page in the footer, are simply missing; I have a blank footer bar. I have already set the default renderer to IPE as well as given appropriate permissions. Any ideas on how to fix this - get the IPE buttons?? There are no missing dependencies AFAIK, but the evidence suggests I am probably wrong..

Comment: First check your permissions, is the user you are logged in with allowed to `Use the Panels In-Place Editor`?

Comment: Yep, permissions are in place.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Node template in page manager? -> /admin/structure/pages
That should make the toolbar appear.